# How can I optimize this query in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, query-optimization, postgresql-performance

The below query is taking more time to run. How can I optimize the below query to run for more records? I have run `Explain Analyze` for this query. Attached the output for the same.

This was the existing query created as a View and taking a long time (more than hours) to return the result.

I have done vacuum, analyze and reindex on these 2 tables but no luck.

```
select st_tr.step_trail_id,
       st_tr.test_id,
       st_tr.trail_id,
       st_tr.step_name, 
       filter.regular_expression as filter_expression,
       filter.order_of_occurrence as filter_order,
       filter.match_type as filter_match_type,
       null as begins_with,
       null as ends_with,
       null as input_source,
       null as pattern_expression,
       null as pattern_matched,
       null as pattern_status,
       null as pattern_order,
       'filter' as record_type
from tab_report_step st_tr, 
     tab_report_filter filter
where st_tr.st_tr_id = filter.st_tr_id)
```

Query plan:

```
 Hash Join  (cost=446852.58..1176380.76 rows=6353676 width=489) (actual time=16641.953..47270.831 rows=6345360 loops=1)
   Buffers: shared hit=1 read=451605 dirtied=5456 written=5424, temp read=154080 written=154074
   -> Seq Scan on tab_report_filter filter  (cost=0..24482.76 rows=6353676 width=161) (actual time=0.041..8097.233 rows=6345360 loops=1)
      Buffers: shared read=179946 dirtied=4531 written=4499
   -> Hash  (cost=318817.7..318817.7 rows=4716070 width=89) (actual time=16627.291..16627.291 rows=4709040 loops=1)
      Buffers: shared hit=1 read=271656 dirtied=925 written=925, temp written=47629
        -> Seq Scan on tab_report_step st_tr  (cost=0..318817.7 rows=4716070 width=89) (actual time=0.059..10215.484 rows=4709040 loops=1)
           Buffers: shared hit=1 read=271656 dirtied=925 written=925
```

Comment: It's a join between 4.7 million records in one table and 6.4 million records in the other table and you want them all. How fast should it be? It's getting about 130 records per millisecond, not that great, but not that bad either. What is your setting for work_mem?

Comment: Thank you for the response. work_mem set as 200MB.

Comment: 47 seconds is certainly not "hours"

Comment: If I use join on st_tr.st_tr_id = filter.st_tr_id, will that improve the performance? Or Is there any better way to optimize this query?

Answer (score 0):

You have *not* run `VACUUM` on these tables. Perhaps `VACUUM (FULL)`, but certainly not `VACUUM`.

There are two things that can be improved:

- Make sure that no pages have to be dirtied or written while you *read* them.  That is most likely because this is the first time you read the rows, and PostgreSQL sets *hint bits*.

  Running `VACUUM` (without `FULL`) would have fix that. Also, if you repeat the experiment, you shouldn't get those dirtied and written buffers any more.
- Give the query more memory by increasing `work_mem`. The hash does not fit in `work_mem` and spills to disk, which causes extra disk reads and writes, which is bad for performance.

Since you join two big tables with no restricting `WHERE` conditions and have a lot of result rows, this query will never be fast.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Yes, I have run VACUUM FULL on both the tables. Will try that with VACUUM. work_mem is 200 MB.